# ¿Como puedo filtrar los datos para llenar una lista para un dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, mvc

Lleno una un DropDownList con datos de un servidor de SAP pero ahora necesito filtrar los datos que lleno dependiendo si el cliente esta valido en el sistema, de esta manera solo me mostrara los clientes que esten activos en la lista desplegable en la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el cliente tiene el valor en el campo de VAlid = tNO el cliente no esta activo, en cambio si esta tYes el cliente esta activo y debe mostrarse en la lista.

El problema que tengo es como puedo hacer el filtro dependiendo de este dato en mi lista.

Este es la clase que uso

```
    public partial class Value
    {
        
        public string OdataEtag { get; set; }
        
        public double QuantityOnStock { get; set; }
       
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
       
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
       
        public string CardName { get; set; }
        
        public string CardCode { get; set; }
        
        public string Valid { get; set; }
    }
```

El codigo que estaba probando es con este pero no me resulto como esperaba

```
  if (value != null)
        {
            
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                var valido = item.Valid;
                if(valido == "tYES"){
                    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listb = from x in value
                                                        select new SelectListItem
                                                        {
                                                            Text = x.CardName,
                                                            Value = 
                                                            x.CardName.ToString()
                                                        };

                    return listb;
                }
               
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con cambiar todo el último código que pusiste por:
(Suponiendo que value es una lista)

```
 if (value != null)
 {
    return new SelectList(value.Where(x=> Valid=="tYES"), "CardName", "CardName")
 }
 return new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>());
```